# Salesforce Profile Analytics Cloud Integration User : Unknown user permission: ViewForecastingPredictive

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-marketing-cloud, salesforce-einstein

Hi When I try to deploy profile, I am getting this error

[Profile Analytics Cloud Integration User] Unknown user permission: ViewForecastingPredictive

Can some one help me understand what this error is, and how to resolve it